# How can I force a UIButton to be released (even if the user is still holding it?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So,

I have a button in my app that when held down, it will record frames from the camera. When the button is released, the output is processed. There is also a 10s max for videos - so after that time it should process the video anyway.

The problem I'm having is that the user is able to continue holding down the button (and if they release it at a later time, it will trigger the completion event) - is there anyway to force the button to be released?

Comment: Use a timer, ignore the touch-up event if the timer fired before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[self performSelector:@selector(functionThatTakesOneArgument:) withObject:myArgument afterDelay:10];` to perform some function after a delay. So if you insert this into your button down code, you can call whatever function does your work.

You would also call `functionThatTakesOneArgument:` in the button up event, so you may want to check that it doesn't go off twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIControlEventTouchDown` , `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchCancel` event, you might add timer in startRecording method :

```
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(startRecording:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]

[button addTarget:target action:@selector(endRecording:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]
```

If you want to cancel touch event on button use:

```
// Call this if you wish to cancel the event tracking
[button cancelTrackingWithEvent:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing the UIButton from the view causes all touch events to cancel. Consider this:

User presses on button and holds. When they first start pressing, call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(endRecording) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

where endRecording is defined as follows:

```
- (void)endRecording {
    if ( [ record_button isHighlighted ] ) {
        [record_button removeFromSuperView];
        [self.view addSubview:record_button];
        // TODO: Finish recording
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this down-voted? If there's a mistake in my code, please let me know so I can learn from my mistake as opposed to just down-voting for no reason.